# Whats the best way to implement a streaming quotes page?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

I have a webservice that gives me the live stock quotes. I need to hit the webservice and update the page every 10 seconds or so.

what is the best way to implement this using .NET and AJAX?

I am looking for tips in the following lines:

1. How to implement the end ASPX page to refresh the content on a timeout event?
2. Should i just implement the front end using custom html calling the aspx page using xmlhttp? sort of old style asp code.

any ideas would be appreciated.

sChar

Comment: "Best way" - best in what? Performance? Speed? Payload? User experience? Ease of development? Speed of development?

Comment: @Oded : Performance on the client/browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this [Javascript News TickerTape Component](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/tickertape-vertical-scroll.html).  It will pull pages of items (stock quotes in your case) in JSON format and display them in a scrolling container.

If you're using .net 3.5 you can create a web service which returns JSON; if not, have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/jsonwebservice.aspx).